# fuel sdk ET_SentEvent inconsistent results

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, fuel-sdk, triggered-send

I am trying to pull the history of triggered send result by email. I have successfully written a test script in C# using the Fuel SDK and the ET_SentEvent call. However, I will run it once against an email address and get like 75 results. I then run it again (identical call) and the second time it returns 0 results. This happens over and over again with different email addresses. First time returns some results, second and ongoing - nothing. Looking at the status and code of the response, it always shows success - 200, so its not a timeout or anythig

Same thing happens when I try the ET_BounceEvent call. i will get some results the first time, then run it again, and nothing.

I have tried both a simple filter of just the email address, and a complex filter of both email and EventDate of greater than 2 months ago (and other dates)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like if you make the calls, it immediatly puts them in a batch of results by default. When you make the next call, it creates a new batch which won't have the previous results in it. So the simple solution is to call :

```
GetSinceLastBatch = false;
```

C# example

```
ET_SentEvent oe = new ET_SentEvent
        {
            AuthStub = myclient,
            GetSinceLastBatch = false,
            SearchFilter = new SimpleFilterPart() { Property = "SubscriberKey", SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.equals, Value = new string[] { email } }
        };
```